CORS Error: It does not have HTTP ok status. GoLang Mux API
I'm trying to make http requests via Angular 17 App. And everytime the browser responds:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/login' from origin
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
HTTP ok status.

In my angular-interceptor is passing this header:
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router,
                private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, nextHandler: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authToken = StorageUtil.getAuthToken();
        let request = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            }
        });
        if (authToken == null || authToken == "") {
            this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']).then(() => {
                return throwError(() => new Error('Você precisa estar logado'));
            });
        }
        if (authToken != null && StorageUtil.isTokenExpired()) {
            this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe((resp) => {
                const accestoken = resp.data.accessToken as string;
                request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${accestoken}`
                    }
                });
                return nextHandler.handle(request);
            })
        }
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
            }
        });
        return nextHandler.handle(request);
    }
}

And my gorilla/mux Go API I pass this middleware to every handler in the server:
func jsonContentTypeMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Enable CORS
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
func main(){
router := app.newRouter() //create my router with gorila/mux 
startServer(jsonContentTypeMiddleware(router))

}
func startServer(handler http.Handler) {
    fmt.Printf("API rodando na porta: %s", webPort)
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:         fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", host, webPort),
        Handler:      handler,
        WriteTimeout: time.Hour,
        ReadTimeout:  time.Hour,
    }
    log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
}


Two tips: 1) Use net/http package rather than gorilla/mux; with Go v1.22's addition of enhanced routing patterns, gorilla/mux is no longer needed, really. 2) Don't implement CORS by hand; instead, depend on some CORS middleware library, such as my own.

can you exclude  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json") when request method is OPTIONS and tell if it makes it any different?

@MohamadKarimisalim I don't expect it would make a difference to a CORS issue.

Please provide a reproducible example; my guess would be that you are not handling the OPTIONS preflight request in router. So the middleware runs (and adds headers) but, as router does not handle the request a 404 is returned (so the fact headers are added is not really relevant). The error you are seeing It does not have HTTP ok status. supports this.

@jub0bs Do you have any article about it to recomend? All the ones I found used gorilla/mux or gin package...

@Brits you are 100% correct, I'll post my answer right away

@rafaelpadu Start with the documentation of net/http.

@rafaelpadu About using CORS in conjunction with v1.22+ of net/http, see https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/cors#example-Middleware.Wrap

As you've come to realise, "manually" implementing CORS is error-prone. You're better off relying on some existing CORS middleware library; you'll find one solution using my own library below.
Besides, with Go v1.22's addition of enhanced routing patterns, the need for third-party routers like gorilla/mux is moot; you can get by with the standard library's net/http package.
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/jub0bs/cors"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("GET /hello", handleHello)

    corsMiddleware, err := cors.NewMiddleware(cors.Config{
        Origins: []string{"*"},
        Methods: []string{
            http.MethodGet,
            http.MethodPost,
            http.MethodPut,
            http.MethodDelete,
        },
        RequestHeaders: []string{
            "Authorization",
            "Content-Type",
            "X-Requested-With",
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:    "localhost:8080",
        Handler: corsMiddleware.Wrap(mux),
        // other settings omitted
    }
    log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
}

func handleHello(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    io.WriteString(w, `{"msg": "Hello, World!"}`)
}


I needed to also responde to the pre-flight request with Http.OK Status, so basically I changed the middleware function as follows:
func jsonContentTypeMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //Enable CORS
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With")

        //this part here
        if r.Method == http.MethodOptions { 
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            return
        }

        // Call the next handler
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}


This is too restrictive, though. Not all OPTIONS requests are preflight requests. See https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly
